# How to collect the data with BeautifulSoup using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to know how I can collect the desire data with beautiful soup here is the code and trying to collect the text data that is "RoSharon1977"

I'm trying using

```
profilePageSource.select("div#twitter-view a[href]")[0].get_text()
```

Here is the code

```
<div id="twitter" class="editable-item">
    <div id="twitter-view">
            <ul><li>
                <a href="/redir/redirect?url=http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter%2Ecom%2FRoSharon1977&amp;urlhash=QRJD">RoSharon1977</a>
            </li></ul>
</div></div>
```

Comment: It works for me. Is this the complete html?

Comment: Yes it is the complete code

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup are you using? Are you show complete code as well?